# Asp.Net MVC: Should a model create Html-Markup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

Is it a common practice, that models in asp.net mvc x could create/produce/return html markup?

Model-class:

```
public interface IMyModel {

     MvcHtmlString GetGrid(string gridId, HtmlHelper htmlHelper);
}


public class MyModel<TRowModel> : IMyModel {

     IList<TModel> GridItems{get;set;}

     public MvcHtmlString GetGrid(string gridId, HtmlHelper helper){

          WebGrid<TRowModel> webGrid = new WebGrid<TRowModel>(gridId, GridItems)
          return webGrid.GetHtml(helper);
     }
}
```

View:

```
@model IMyModel

@Model.GetGrid("grid", Html)
```

Comment: I some cases I'd say that there's no problem in generating HTML trough the model. In this case, it seams to me that you're just creating a grid and that it has nothing to do with a "model". The `GetGrid` method would best go in (static?) helper class.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the part with the list of items to show in the grid. Thats why it didnt work with html helper (i think).

Comment: Your view should create HTML, not the model.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change my mind :). You could still get your grid from a helper and you could define an input parameter, which would accept your model (i.e. `GridItems`).

Comment: A model/view model should contain the properties you want to display/edit but should not be responsible for how it renders. That is the responsibility of the view

Comment: @AndreiV The problem is, that the grid Items are generic.

Comment: They might be generic but you have access to the metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per MVC pattern, Model should be dumb and should be acting more as containing business domain object. Technically it is possible to send data as HTML in Model but ideally it should be the duty of View to send HTML markup... Model will be inserting data into that HTML markup.